# Sequalize query using sub query and case Then statements

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using sequalize ORM for my project to handle SQL queries.but i have used simple queries now i want to convert this complex SQL raw query into sequalize ORM.

```
    SELECT
    u.uid
FROM
    users u
WHERE
    u.uid NOT IN(
        SELECT 
DISTINCT
            CASE
        WHEN uid = 3 THEN
            blocked_uid
        WHEN uid <> 3 THEN
            uid
        END AS 'uid'
        FROM
            user_block
        WHERE
            `status` = 'ACTIVE'
        AND(
            (uid IN(4, 5) AND blocked_uid = 3)
            OR(uid = 3 AND blocked_uid IN(4, 5))
        )
    )
AND u.uid IN(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query function and bind the parameters or use replacements for the values in the WHERE/IN clauses, as per the documentation http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/#replacements.

ex:

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = ?',
{ replacements: ['active'], type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT 
}).then(function(projects) {
  console.log(projects)
})
```